# One to one relationship - code first

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to make one to one relationship. I don't want to use fluent API if it is not necessary. This is what I tried so far:

```
 [Table("UserProfile")]
public class UserProfile
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}
  public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public UserProfile UserProfile { get; set; }

}
```

Yes, I know there are few similar questions outhere, but none of them were short and clear. Lot of them also did not work.

Comment: Thank you .Down vote helps.

Comment: Can we check which version of MVC and EF you are using - it might matter in your answers.

Comment: MVC 4,Entity Framework 5

Comment: Ok, have tested my answer in that, and it works. See if it works for you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends a little on what type of table structure you want to achieve. There are various ways of doing this, and there is a good walkthrough for all the options, from [Shared Primary Key Assocations](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2011/04/14/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-3-shared-primary-key-associations.aspx) to [One-to-One Foreign Key Associations](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2011/05/01/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-5-one-to-one-foreign-key-associations.aspx) in those links. Unfortunately those links make more use of Fluent than Annotations. The samples below use Annotations, as you need.

**Shared Primary Key**

In theory the Shared Primary Key (horizontal table partitioning, in database terms) is the "correct way". It is also the smallest change you need to do to be able to generate a migration (which will use a Shared Primary Key Association). Note that I would change `Person.Id` to `Person.UserId` to better show your intent:

```
// tested in EF 5 and MVC 4.5.
[Table("UserProfile")]
public class UserProfile {
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}
[Table("Person")] // not required, added for clarity in sample code
public class Person {
    // Note the change of property name to reflect that this is a shared primary key,
    //  using the UserId column in UserProfile as the Primary Key
    [Key]
    public int UserId { get; set; } 
    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public virtual UserProfile UserProfile { get; set; }
}
// The generated migration:
public partial class AddTable_Person : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up() {
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.Person",
            c => new {
                    UserId = c.Int(nullable: false),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.UserId)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.UserProfile", t => t.UserId)
            .Index(t => t.UserId);
    }
    public override void Down(){
        DropIndex("dbo.Person", new[] { "UserId" });
        DropForeignKey("dbo.Person", "UserId", "dbo.UserProfile");
        DropTable("dbo.Person");
    }
}
```

this then gives you, in effect a `1:0-1` relationship between `UserProfile` (which is mandatory) and `People` (which is optional, but can have one per person at the most.

If you want to use `Id` in `Person` then do the following (the migration will change accordingly):

```
public class Person {
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Id")]
    public UserProfile UserProfile { get; set; }
}
```

**Shared Primary Key with two-way navigation**

If you want to navigate from `UserProfile` to `Person` you have more work to do. Simply adding `public virtual Person Person { get; set; }` to UserProfile will give you an error:

> Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the types 'Test.Models.UserProfile' and 'Test.Models.Person'. The principal end of this association must be explicitly configured using either the relationship fluent API or data annotations.

So, we fix it with `[Required]` on the `Person.UserProfile` property (`Person` requires `UserProfile`). This gives the same migration as before.

```
// tested in EF 5 and MVC 4.5.
[Table("UserProfile")]
public class UserProfile {
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
}
[Table("Person")] // not required, added for clarity in sample code
public class Person {
    [Key]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    [Required]
    public virtual UserProfile UserProfile { get; set; }
}
```

Again, this works if you use `Id` for `Person` instead of `UserId`:

```
public class Person {
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Id")]
    [Required]
    public virtual UserProfile UserProfile { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: +1: Good analysis! Strange thing I found is that for the two-way navigation adding `[ForeignKey("UserProfile")]` on `Person.UserId` works without `[Required]` attribute and without FK attribute in `UserProfile`, but it does not work to put `[ForeignKey("UserId")]` without `[Required]` attribute on `Person.UserProfile` - unless you remove the `UserProfile.Person` navigation property. Totally confusing for me...

Comment: @Slauma. It does, although I prefer it with `Required` on the `virtual UserProfile` property as it helps declare intent - purely personal preference though.

Answer (score 0):

```
[Table("UserProfile")]
public class UserProfile
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public virtual Person Person {get;set;}
}

public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int UserProfileUserId { get; set; } //Foreign Key
    public virtual UserProfile UserProfile { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: It does not work. This is why I said there is really huge  number of uncorrect answers at this topic. That's why I like so much the person which downvoted.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a one-to-one relationship the first thing you must clarify is what is the principal and what the dependent entity in this relationship. Can a `Person` exist without `UserProfile` or can a `UserProfile` exist without `Person`?

Because you have started to apply a `[ForeignKey]` attribute in `Person` I am assuming now that `Person` is the dependent, i.e. it cannot exist without `UserProfile`.

Correct application of the `[ForeignKey]` attribute would then be:

```
public class Person
{
    [ForeignKey("UserProfile")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public UserProfile UserProfile { get; set; }
}
```

I am not sure if that is sufficient because you don't have a `Person` navigation property in `UserProfile`. If it doesn't work add this property to `UserProfile`:

```
public Person Person { get; set; }
```

If you don't want to have such a navigation property you can't avoid Fluent API:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
    .HasRequired(p => p.UserProfile)
    .WithOptional();
```

Comment: IMHO, `modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
    .HasRequired(p => p.UserProfile)
    .WithOptional();` is FLUENT API code that the user doesn't want to use..

Comment: I can use fluent api, it is not problem, I would also like navigational properties, yes, Person cannot exist without UserProfile

Comment: @BhushanFirake: "*if it is not necessary*", he said. But it is (possibly) necessary if he doesn't want to have a `UserProfile.Person` navigation property. He has the choice: Either navigation property or Fluent API. Possibly it is not necessary even without the navigation property because the FK attribute refers to the PK and maybe EF is smart enough to figure out that a FK which is  a PK at the same time only can participate in a one-to-one relationship. I am not sure about that.

Comment: How surprising, it does not work. Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the types... This is what I have so far in UserProfile table: int Id (primary key),string UserName, navigation property Person Person. In Person table I have int Id (primary key), and navigation property UserProfile UserProfile which has [ForeignKey("Id")] annotation.

Comment: @impeRAtoR: Yes, surprise... The `[ForeignKey]` attribute must sit on the `Id` property: `[ForeignKey("UserProfile")]`. See my edited code. I don't know why it matters for one-to-one relationships. For one-to-many relationships both versions (FK attribute either on FK or on navigation property) are supported.